# Are "show off your DE" questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking to customize my DE, and I would like to ask the community for screenshots + config file examples.

Something like [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=45692)

Would a question like that be on or off topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm... I'm debating that I might close this not as 'off topic', as it is *unix*,  but as 'not a real question'. Can you show me any examples from any other SE sites ( SO, SF preferred ) where this kind of question wasn't closed?

Comment: well.. http://serverfault.com/questions/124578/what-is-your-favorite-tn3270-client, but i was just really wondering which SE site would be most appropiate to ask that kindof question? ( maybe superuser ? )

Comment: @Stefan well the problem here is that you aren't really asking a question... that SF question is looking for 'good monospaced fonts' I might allow it if it was worded 'Good dark theme for KDE' with a note to 'please include screenshots'. But just 'show off your de' simply seems like "not a real question"

Comment: @Stefan I do not think there is a SE site that allows you to say "show off your stuff" I think a question worded the way you've worded this will be closed anywhere. However, I might be wrong... there is the whole, cli tricks thread, that I don't particularly agree with, but ignore.